# Mostrar Opciones de Menu Segun Perfil de Usuario

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, aplicación-web, webforms

tengo un menu lateral en html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código:

```
<li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Administración</a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li>
            <a href="Usuarios.aspx">Usuarios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Perfiles.aspx">Perfiles</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Logs.aspx">Logs</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Estoy trabajando con webforms.

¿Cómo muestro las opciones de menu segun el perfil de usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma es que se encargue el servidor. Por cada elemento del menú puedes crear un "li" y añadirlo dinámicamente a "homeSubmenu". Algo así:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
homeSubmenu.Controls.Add(li);

HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "pagina.htm");
anchor.InnerText = "Elemento de menú 1";
li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

Esto de forma recursiva para cada elemento que el usuario debe tener.